# Plot separated variables with same Case-variable geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Two variables plot together when plotting by "Case" N, can I separate them so they plot with two different lines?

See green dots have two values per x-Sample and are plotted as same green line.

```
data <- tibble::tibble(
  value = c(0.0693, 0.0677, 0.0727, 0.0650, 0.0908, 0.00112,    0.131,  0.0975, 0.109,  0.105,  0.0927, 0.0552, 0.0532, 0.0559, 0.0771, 0.0563, 0.0551,
0.191,  0.193,  0.147,  0.157,  0.258,  0.00738,    0.00808,    0.00661,    0.00495210983601696,    0.451,  0.379,  0.0653, 0.0350, 0.0559, 0.192,  0.0738, 0.107,
0.0138, 0.0104, 0.0145, 0.0103, 5.08255237961193E-05,   0.0361, 0.0264, 0.0454, 0.0277, 0.0117, 8.92140244446427E-05,   0.0173727368061961, 0.0108, 8.54627809588924E-05,   2.35593459925552E-05,   3.13020069803476E-05,   1.12019464502152E-05, 
0.0453, 0.0577, 0.0627, 0.0450, 0.0508, 0.00212,    0.031,  0.0875, 0.100,  0.115,  0.0827, 0.0452, 0.0332, 0.0459, 0.0671, 0.0263, 0.0451), 
Sample = rep(c(1:17),4),
Variable = rep(c(paste0("A",rep(1:4))),17),
Case = rep(c("P",rep("N",2),"L" ), 17))

ggplot(data, aes(x=Sample, y=value, color=Case)) + 
  geom_line() +
 geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group = interaction(Variable, Cases)`:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=Sample, y=value, color=Case, group = interaction(Variable,Case))) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If you want different colors for each you can pass `color = interaction(Varaible, Case)`.

Does it answer your question ?